# Spring : CSS, JS not loading

Tags: javascript, java, css, spring, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which I have CSS, JS files and they are not loading although they are properly called. What am I doing wrong?

Resources folder :

```
Project --> webapp --> resources--> css, js directories
```

Config :

root-context.xml :

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.APP">
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    </context:component-scan>


    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
                destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <beans:property name="url"
                        value="jdbc:postgresql://IP:PORT/DBNAME"/>
        <beans:property name="username" value="DBUSER"/>
        <beans:property name="password" value="DBPASS"/>
        <beans:property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/>
        <beans:property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="20"/>
        <beans:property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
                class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="com.APP.model"/>

        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</beans:prop>
                   <beans:prop key="hibernate.order_updates">true</beans:prop>-->
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="cache.use_second_level_cache">true</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="cache.use_query_cache">true</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="LoginServiceImpl" class="com.APPName.service.LoginServiceImpl"/>

    <task:annotation-driven/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <cache:annotation-driven />

    <beans:bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager">
        <beans:property name="caches">
            <beans:set>
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean"
                            p:name="person"/>
            </beans:set>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>



</beans:beans>
```

servlet-context.xml :

```
<security:global-method-security
            secured-annotations="enabled"
            jsr250-annotations="disabled"
            pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.App" use-default-filters="false">
        <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    </context:component-scan>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

    <resources mapping="/resources/" location="/resources/"/>

    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean class="com.App.service.DoNotTruncateMyUrls"/>

    <beans:bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <beans:property name="maxUploadSize" value="2147483648"/>
    </beans:bean>
    <!--  52428800 -->


</beans:beans>
```

security-applicationContext.xml :

```
  <security:http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>
    <security:http create-session="ifRequired" use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" disable-url-rewriting="true">
        <security:form-login login-page="/login" username-parameter="j_username" password-parameter="j_password"
                             login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" default-target-url="/dashboard"
                             always-use-default-target="true" authentication-failure-url="/denied"/>
        <security:remember-me key="_spring_security_remember_me" user-service-ref="userDetailsService"
                              token-validity-seconds="1209600" data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
        <security:logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"/>
        <security:port-mappings>
            <security:port-mapping http="8080" https="8443"/>
        </security:port-mappings>
        <security:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/" success-handler-ref="myLogoutHandler"/>

        <security:session-management session-fixation-protection="migrateSession">
            <security:concurrency-control session-registry-ref="sessionReg" max-sessions="5" expired-url="/login"/>
        </security:session-management>
    </security:http>

    <beans:bean id="sessionReg" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl"/>

    <beans:bean id="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider"
                class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices">
        <beans:constructor-arg index="0" value="_spring_security_remember_me"/>
        <beans:constructor-arg index="1" ref="userDetailsService"/>
        <beans:constructor-arg index="2" ref="jdbcTokenRepository"/>
        <property name="alwaysRemember" value="true"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="jdbcTokenRepository"
                class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl">
        <beans:property name="createTableOnStartup" value="false"/>
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Remember me ends here -->
//Auth mechanisms
</beans>
```

Screenshot :

[image]

JSP :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ page session="true" %>
<html>

<body>
        <nav class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5">
            <ul class="pull-right">
                <li class="purple"><a href="#"><i class="icons icon-user-3"></i> Login</a>
                    <ul id="login-dropdown" class="box-dropdown">
                        <li>
                            <form id="form" action="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check'/>"  method="POST">
                                <div class="box-wrapper">
                                    <h4>LOGIN</h4>

                                    <div class="iconic-input">
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="j_username" id="j_username">
                                        <i class="icons icon-user-3"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="iconic-input">
                                        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="j_password" id="j_password">
                                        <i class="icons icon-lock"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="checkbox"  id="_spring_security_remember_me" name="_spring_security_remember_me"> <label for="_spring_security_remember_me">Remember me</label>
                                    <br>
                                    <br>
                                    <div class="pull-left">
                                        <input name="submit" type="submit" class="orange" value="Login">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="pull-right">
                                        <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
                                        <br>
                                        <a href="#">Forgot your username?</a>
                                        <br>
                                    </div>
                                    <br class="clearfix">
                                </div>

                                <div class="footer">
                                    <h4 class="pull-left">NEW CUSTOMER?</h4>
                                    <a class="button pull-right" href="create_an_account.html">Create an account</a>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="icons icon-lock"></i> Create an Account</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <c:url var="add" value="/displayproducts" ></c:url>
        <form:form action="${add}" commandName="product">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <form:label path="productname">
                            <spring:message text="productname"/>
                        </form:label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form:input path="productname"  />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form:form>




<c:url var="addAction" value="/user/add" ></c:url>
<form:form action="${addAction}" commandName="user">
<div class="row">

<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 register-account">

<div class="carousel-heading no-margin">
    <h4>Register</h4>
</div>

<div class="page-content">
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <p><strong>Tausch information</strong></p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <p>E-Mail*</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
        <form:input type="text" path="email"/>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <p>Username*</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
        <form:input type="text" path="username"/>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <p>Password</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
        <form:input type="password" path="password"/>
    </div>

</div>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <input class="big" type="submit" value="<spring:message text="Register"/>">
        <input class="big" type="reset" value="Cancel">
    </div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</form:form>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you getting 404 or 401 for your requests?

Comment: @aksappy : 200, the page is loaded, but html, css and all is not, adding screenshot in 2 mins.

Comment: I didnt found any css in your code..

Answer (score 0):

```
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Add ${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ to your link.

Comment: CSS code directly added in JSP is also not loading.

Comment: could you add your jsp.

Comment: Added. Check it out.

Comment: I am sure you are trying to build a login screen, So if you want responsive screen go to http://w3layouts.com .   https://w3layouts.com/free-web-elements/

Answer (score 0):

Your code : `<resources mapping="/resources/" location="/resources/"/>`

Try :       `<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>`

OR :        `<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all required CSS files are under resources folder as in security-applicationContext.xml file you have the following line:

```
<security:http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>
```

If you are correctly done that, for further debugging put the **`<debug>`**
tag in your security-applicationContext.xml file and if you are using any logging framework (like log4j) enable the logging for "org.springframework.security" package at **DEBUG** level. 
The above configuration will enable the debug level logs of spring security.